# find sum of products of n factors each <m

Tags: combinatorics

How can one show that the sum of all products of n positive integers, each of which is less than or equal to the positive integer m, is given by the Stirling number of the second kind, S(n+m,m)? For example, for n=2 and m=3, there are 6 such products: 3x3, 3x2, 3x1, 2x2, 2x1, 1x1; and their sum = 25 = S(5,3).

Comment: To be clear, the result seems to be ${n+m \brace m}$?

Comment: For example, for n=3 and m=5, there are 35 such products, including: : 
5x5x3 =75,  5x5x5 = 125,  3x3x2 = 18, 4x3x3 = 36, etc.
 The sum of the 35 products  = 1050 = S(8,5).

Comment: Yes, I see you are using the Karamata-Knuth notation.

Comment: Maybe you should include your first comment in your original post as an edit, since it shows some of the progress you have made. Is there anything else you have tried to show the identity?

Comment: Also, could you be a little more explicit in the conditions of the problem, as there are a few ambiguities. For example, would $5\times 5\times 3$ and $5\times 3\times 5$ both be included? Also, would $8\times 2\times 1$ and $4\times 4\times 1$ both be included?

Comment: Thanks, products of same factors but different order are not included. Repetitions of factors are allowed: 4x4x1, 1x1x1, etc.  Both 4x3x2 (=24) and 2x6x2 (=24) are allowed.

Comment: Thanks, products of same factors, but in different order are not included. Repetitions of factors are allowed: 4x4x1, 1x1x1, etc.  Both 4x3x2 (=24) and 2x6x2 (=24) are allowed. Your example 8x2x1 would not be allowed for n=3, m=5, of course. I suspect you used it owing to the term n+m (here, 3+5) in the Karamata-Knuth expression. Thank you so much for helping me clarify the question. The space allotted in the site window is a constant concern for me. I hope it is clear enough now; if not, please let me know of further questions. Thanks again!

Comment: I was just including that example to determine if the products to be distinct. I think you intended that different expressions for a product were allowed e.g. if $4\times 3\times 2$ and $2\times 6\times 2$ would both be included despite the fact that their products were the same. I don't think you answered my first doubt (and perhaps I wasn't clear enough). I was asking if different permutations of a product were considered distinct or not. I.e. would $4\times 3\times 2$ and $2\times 3\times 4$ both be considered difference and hence each be included in the sum?

Comment: I have edited the question per your cogent questions. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: No, 4x3x2 and 2x3x4 would not both be included Only one permutation would be included. But unique products with the same value ( 4×3×2 and  2×6×2) would be included. (However, the product 2x6x2 would not of course appear among the products in the example I gave, for 3 factors, with max value of each = 5.)

Comment: As for a hint to the problem, I think trying to establish a recursion might be useful. There is a pretty well known recursion for stirling numbers of the second kind, so you might want to see if you can try to match them.

Comment: I actually derived this result (after working on it for some time) before I knew what Stirling numbers of either kind were, but have since misplaced that work, and had hoped to find an existing proof, which would probably be more efficient than my earlier one, anyway. I developed a number of recursions in the course of that work and my derivation no doubt depended upon them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function $f(m,n)$ to return the sum of all products of the elements of $n$ positive integers, each of which is less than or equal to the positive integer $m$.

Let's first start with some terminology/syntax to make things clear. I will use a small example of $n=3$ and $m=3$ to make things clear. First consider all possible triples of integers that are multiplied together. These are
$$(3,3,3);(3,3,2);(3,3,1);(3,2,2);(3,2,1);(3,1,1);(2,2,2);(2,2,1);(2,1,1);(1,1,1)$$
Notice that elements of each of these **$\mathbf{n}$-tuples** are in nonincreasing order. Moreover, we have lexographically ordered all the tuples in decreasing order e.g. $(3,3,3)$ is before $(3,3,2)$ or $(3,1,1)$ is before $(2,2,2)$

In general terms for general $m,n$, let's denote the set of all $n$-tuples as $\mathcal{S}$, where the tuple starting from lexographically highest is $s_1$ and $s_i$ is lexographically higher than $s_{i+1}$ for all relevant $i$. We can show with stars-and-bars that
$$|\mathcal{S}|=\binom{m+n-1}{n}$$
Since it is not essential to the solving of the problem, I will leave that as an exercise to the reader. This means that $s_{\binom{m+n-1}{n}}$ is the lexographically smallest tuple and will be composed of $n$ $1$'s.

Moreover, denote the product of the elements in a tuple $s_i$ as $p_i$. We have that
$$f(m,n)=\sum_{i=1}^\binom{m+n-1}{n} p_i$$

---

Now for solving the actual problem, consider the $n$-tuples that have a first element of $m$ (most importantly, these are the only tuples that contain at least one $m$). Using a similar stars-and-bars reasoning, it is not hard to see that there are $\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}$ $n$-tuples that have a first element of $m$. Since these are the elements $s_1$ through $s_\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}$. Hence, their sum is
$$\sum_{i=1}^\binom{m+n-2}{n-1} p_i$$
Since each of these $p_i$ terms contain a factor of $m$, we can factor that out. What we are left with is all the $p_i$ terms for all the $(n-1)$-tuples that contain  positive integer elements that are at most $m$. Hence, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^\binom{m+n-2}{n-1} p_i$$
$$=m\cdot f(m,n-1)$$

Now, consider the remaining elements of $\mathcal{S}$ that do not contain $m$. The sum of all these $p_i$ terms will of course be the sum of the $p_i$ terms for all $n$-tuples that contain positive integer elements that are at most $m-1$. Hence, we have
$$\sum_{i=\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}+1}^\binom{m+n-1}{n} p_i$$
$$=f(m-1,n)$$

Combining these ideas, we have
$$f(m,n)=\sum_{i=1}^\binom{m+n-1}{n} p_i$$
$$f(m,n)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\binom{m+n-2}{n-1} p_i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=\binom{m+n-2}{n-1}+1}^\binom{m+n-1}{n} p_i\right)$$
$$\boxed{f(m,n)=m\cdot f(m,n-1)+f(m-1,n)}$$
We can also computationally determine that
$$f(1,1)=1$$

Now consider the stirling numbers of the second kind that are in the form $\begin{Bmatrix} m+n\\m\end{Bmatrix}$. Using the recursive definition of the stirling numbers of the second kind, we know that they follow the recursion
$$\begin{Bmatrix} m+n\\m\end{Bmatrix}=m\begin{Bmatrix} m+n-1\\m\end{Bmatrix}+\begin{Bmatrix} m+n-1\\m-1\end{Bmatrix}$$
With initial condition
$$\begin{Bmatrix} 1+0\\1\end{Bmatrix}=1$$

We see that $f(m,n)$ and $\begin{Bmatrix} m+n\\m\end{Bmatrix}$ follow the same recursion and have the same initial conditions. Hence, they must be the same.

Comment: Thanks, well done! I had found the recursion f(m,n) = m F(m,n-1) +f(n-1,m) and was going to post it. I had not yet thought to check Stirling recursions (per your suggestion) for the same form. As I suspected would be the case, this derivation is decidedly more efficient than mine. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to add that in my original work, I was yet unaware of Stirling numbers, so could not have reasoned in this manner. I derived an expression for the sum of all products which I only later came to understand as the expression for "Stirling numbers of the second kind". Thanks again for this proof.

Answer (score 2):

We have from first principles the generating function (here the term $r^k
z^k$ means that we choose the value $r$ exactly $k$  times for a
contribution to the product of $r^k$ by way of $k$ factors)

$$\prod_{r=1}^m (1 +  rz + r^2 z^2 + \cdots)$$

Hence the desired quantity is given by (extract contribution of $n$ factors)

$$[z^n] \prod_{r=1}^m \frac{1}{1-rz}
= [z^{n+m}] \prod_{r=1}^m \frac{z}{1-rz}.$$

But this last generating function is precisely the [OGF of the Stirling
numbers of the second
kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_functions) and we get

$$[z^{n+m}] \sum_{p\ge m} {p\brace m} z^p
= {n+m\brace m}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Thanks; I am of course now familiar with the use of { } for Stirling mumbers of 2nd kind, but I am unsure concerning your use of [ ] outside the summations and continued products. Could you explicate that usage? Thanks again.

Comment: This is a [coefficient extractor from formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients).